# double integral : multiply by a variable considered as constant

Tags: integration

$$ \int_{0}^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x}{y^2 x^2 +1}dx dy$$
I know that the integration will be simpler if we integrate first with respect to y..
But if I want to integrate first with respect to x , Can I multiply and divide by 
$$2 y^2$$ since y is considered as constant 
$$ \int_{0}^1 \int_0^1 \frac{2 y^2 x}{(y^2 x^2 +1)(2 y^2)}dx dy$$
Then we do integration by parts ..We have 2 functions : one of them has the numerator is the differentiation of the denominator, so it is simple to integrate.

I am not asking about this problem specifically .. But in general , Can we do this ? can we multiply and divide by functions of the variable which is considered constant ?

Answer (score 2):

More than "constant", it is just independent from $x$. So, yes,
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{y^2 x^2+1}\,dx = \frac{\log(1+y^2)}{2y^2} \tag{1}$$
and:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+y^2)}{2y^2}\,dy = \int_{0}^{1}\arctan(x)\,dx = \frac{\pi-2\log 2}{4}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: So you mean if the limits of x are functions of y , we can not do this ?

Comment: @MCS: $\int_{A}^{B}f(x)\,dx = F(B)-F(A)$. If $A$ and $B$ are functions of $y$, there is no issue.